Checking my interpretation of the odds ratio in OLR
I have run an ordinal logistic regression (response variable is "classification" with three ordered levels: control, intermediary group, and disease group). The predictor variable is a continuous measurement (in cm) and is included with covariates of age and head size.
I am just wanting to confirm if the following sentence is correct, given a statistically significant p-value (< .05) and an odds ratio of 1.20:
"for every 1cm increase, the odds of being classified as either in the intermediary group or in the disease group relative to being classified as the control group increased by 20%."
Thank you for reading.
EDIT:
Hi all - this question: What is an intuitive but accurate way to explain the results of an ordinal regression? contains some good information that helped me with wording this better. Hope it's helpful to others.
